# MultiConverter return UnsetValue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to compare two dates selected from two `DatePicker`s, if the end date is lower than start date the button must be disabled, this is my xaml structure:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="StartDate" />
<DatePicker x:Name="EndDate" />

<Button>
  <Button.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
          <DataTrigger.Binding>
            <MultiBinding>
              <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <Converters:DateComparer />
              </MultiBinding.Converter>
              <Binding ElementName="StartDate" Path="SelectedDate"/>
              <Binding ElementName="EndDate" Path="SelectedDate" />
            </MultiBinding>
          </DataTrigger.Binding>
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>                             
  </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

this is my converter:

```
public class DateComparer : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length < 2)
            return false;

        DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(values[0].ToString(),
                "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(values[1].ToString(),
                "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        //La data finale è minore della data iniziale
        if (endDate < startDate)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

on the `values` object I get Unsect Value, why?

Comment: The selected date on a datepicker is datetime?. Just null check and cast to datetime to compare cast to datetime.

Comment: It's unclear why you have this DataTrigger at all. You could as well directly assign the MultiBinding to the IsEnabled property.

Comment: @Clemens you can't compare two date in a multibinding

Comment: What do you mean? You would use the same converter of course, with inverted result or inverted comparison.

Comment: @Clemens from your comment I though you were referring to compare two date from xaml only. As I wrote in the question, my converter should check if `EndDate` is lower than `StartDate`, if yes, then the trigger must disable the button. Actually the Nik fix does not working, mine too.. Oh, and I know why I get `Unsect` value, I don't know why I get `Unset` value with my code, so the duplicate is useless for me.

Comment: @Clemens you could write an example, I don't know what is unclear for you.

Comment: It is not clear why you do not directly bind IsEnabled, instead of setting it by a DataTrigger. So why do you think you need the DataTrigger?

Comment: @Clemens the `DataTrigger` evaluate a single property, here I have two datepicker which I need to evaluate two dates, for this I used a MultiBinding, I don't know if you know another way to handle this

Comment: Put the following into your Style instead of the DataTrigger: `<Setter Property="IsEnabled"><Setter.Value><MultiBinding ...>...</MultiBinding></Setter.Value></Setter>`.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your xaml, there is nothing to initialize `SelectedDate` when the window is first launched, thus it is null. I was able to make it work with your xaml as is, but I had to make some modifications to the converter.

1. You don't need to call `ToString()` on your values and then parse them. They are already `DateTime`
2. Use the `is` operator. That both does the `null` check and discards the unset values during initialization.

Try this as you `Convert` method:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
                      object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool ret = false;
    if (values.Length > 1 && values[0] is DateTime && values[1] is DateTime)
    {
        DateTime startDate = (DateTime)values[0];
        DateTime endDate = (DateTime)values[1];
        ret = endDate < startDate;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: when  I change the date the converter does not work, but maybe there is another way to disable the button if endDate is lower than startdate directly in xaml?

Comment: just check for the values if they are equal to DependencyProperty.UnsetValue and return false, this will remove initial stage issues.